# Imprimindo a variável de maior valor

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando imprimir a variável com maior valor, porém o valor é sempre N1.
Como faço para imprimir o valor correto?

```
var n1 = 4;
var n2 = 7;
var n3 = 6;

if (n1 > n2, n3) {
console.log("N1 é a maior variável")
} else if (n2 > n1, n3) {
console.log("N2 é a maior variável")
} else{
console.log("N3 é a maior variável")
};
```

Comment: Conhece os operadores lógicos ? da uma olhada na documentação https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos

Comment: eu nao conheço naao, mas nesse exemplo que eu citei acima, entao eu nao vou usar if else?

Comment: Não é possível saber o propósito do código, mas normalmente, em situações assim, você não vai utilizar um algoritmo que simplesmente compare valores pré inicializados, até porque, na prática, não faria sentido.
A melhor maneira de deixar o código mais utilizável é criar uma variável maiorValor, iniciar ela com zero (no caso de conter somente números positivos) e realizar as comparações. Ao final, é só imprimir a variável maiorValor.

Comment: é que sao exercicios para aprender como funciona o javascript, mass brigadaa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Utilizando a base que os colegas acima enviaram eu montei algo um pouco mais descritivo, talvez seja útil para você nesse começo.

Para ajudar vou tentar explicar de uma forma simples o sobre 2 operadores lógicos que são mais utilizados no começo o `||` e o `&&`.

O `||` é um operador lógico que traduzido significa 'OR', ou em português 'OU'. Ele é utilizado quando pelo menos uma de suas condições seja verdadeira.

O `&&` é um operador lógico que traduzido significa 'AND', ou em português 'E'. Ele é utilizado quando todas as suas condições sejam verdadeiras.

No seu caso foi utilizado o && pois era necessário que o valor testado fosse maior que todos os outros ao mesmo tempo.

Espero ter ajudado. Vou deixar um [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_logicos) que pode ser útil tambem.

```
  //Declaração das variáveis.
  var valor1 = 3;
  var valor2 = 9;
  var valor3 = 1;

  //Condições para encontrar o maior valor.

  //Caso o valor1 seja maior que o valor2 E valor1 seja maior que valor3 (O valor1 é o maior).
  if (valor1 > valor2 && valor1 > valor3) {
      console.log("O valor 1 é o maior")
  } 
  //Caso o valor2 seja maior que o valor1 E valor2 seja maior que valor3 (O valor2 é o maior).
  else if (valor2 > valor1 && valor2 > valor3) {
      console.log("O Valor 2 é o maior")
  } 
  //Caso não seja o valor1 nem o valor2, então quer dizer que o valor3 é o maior.
  else {
      console.log("O valor 3 é o maior")
  };
```

Comment: @ViniciusMacedo, embora a dúvida do autor seja relacionada a operadores, o que teria outras duplicatas, como essa reposta seria útil pra outros usuários se considerar que n1,n2 e n3, de fato, representam `N'?

Answer (score 2):

Usa isso:

```js
var n1 = 4;
var n2 = 7;
var n3 = 6;
        
if (n1 > n2 && n1>n3) {
  console.log("N1 é a maior variável")
} else if (n2 > n1 && n2>n3) {
  console.log("N2 é a maior variável")
} else{
  console.log("N3 é a maior variável")
};
```

Comment: aah, brigada pakdapsdoakdd <3

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma outra alternativa, mas seria necessário alterar a sua estrutura de entrada para ao invés de variáveis montar um objeto e utilizá-las como propriedades do mesmo.

```js
//convertendo a sua entrada em um objeto
var entrada = {
  N1: 4,
  N2: 7,
  N3: 6
}

var imprimeMaior = function(input) {
  //criando a estrutura para armazenar e comparar o maior valor 
  var maior = {
    nome: null,
    valor: null
  };

  //percorrendo todos as propriedades do objeto de entrada
  for (item in input) {
    //se for maior ele armazena
    if (input[item] > maior.valor) {
      maior.nome = item;
      maior.valor = input[item];

    }
  }
  console.log(maior.nome + " é a maior variável");

}

//executando o método
imprimeMaior(entrada);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Para evitar vários ifs elses caso sejam muitos valores a testar indico a biblioteca  [**Underscore.js**](https://underscorejs.org/)

Underscore.js é uma pequena biblioteca de códigos utilitários voltados principalmente para a manipulação de estrutura de dados.

Por míseros 14kb você ganha funcionalidades como map, select e invoke, além de uma engine de templating que, por si só, já faz valer o uso da biblioteca.

Outro ponto legal é que os scripts procuram sempre utilizar recursos nativos do navegador, ou seja, em browsers modernos a biblioteca tira proveito das implementações de forEach, map, indexOf, filter etc.

```js
var n1 = 4;
var n2 = 7;
var n3 = 6;
var n4 = 8;
var n5 = 3;
var n6 = 5;
var n7 = 2;
var n8 = 1;

var obj = {
    n1: n1,
    n2: n2,
    n3: n3,
    n4: n4,
    n5: n5,
    n6: n6,
    n7: n7,
    n8: n8

};

var maior = _.max(Object.keys(obj), function (o) {
    return obj[o];
});


console.log(maior);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mas aí não retornaria o nome da variável com maior valor

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, ops, foi mal, entendi errado. Vou apresentar uma biblioteca bem legal para isso e outras coisas